# grunt-react task just hangs when I try to run it

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, reactjs

I'm trying to automate .jsx template compiling. I'm using grunt to achieve this goal. But at the moment my grunt task for .jsx compiling just hangs and nothing happens...

I added NPM package [grunt-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-react). Then I added configuration for it:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ){
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-react');

    grunt.initConfig({
        react: {
            dynamic_mappings: {
                files: [
                    /* ui-components compiling */
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: './scripts/components',
                        src: ['**/**.jsx'],
                        dest: './scripts/components/dest',
                        ext: '.js'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('react', ['react']);
};
```

Then I trying to run this task using grunt `grunt react` and the task is hangs... and nothing happens. It's looks like some process running, but in reality nothing happens.

Grunt versions:
`grunt-cli v0.1.13`
`grunt v0.4.5`

Operating system Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned the issue and got the solution. On June 12th, 2015, the React team has deprecated `JSTransform` and `react-tools`, which `grunt-react` package uses. Instead this module author recomend to use Babel.

I installed Babel and related packages using command:

`npm install --save-dev grunt-babel babel-preset-es2015 babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx babel-preset-react`

Then I configured my `Gruntfile.js` to use Babel for compiling .jsx files to .js:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ){
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        babel: {
            options: {
                plugins: ['transform-react-jsx'],
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            },
            jsx: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: './scripts/components',
                    src: ['*.jsx'],
                    dest: './scripts/components',
                    ext: '.js'
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('react', ['babel']);
};
```

And now, when I run the command `grunt react` my react .jsx components is compiling.